# Weird situation in prime number checking code

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

When I was solving a problem for Project Euler, it asked me to sum up all the primes below 2 million. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int isPrime(int);
int main() {
    long long int sum = 0;
    int i; // index
    for(i = 2 ; i < 2000000 ; i++) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    printf("%lli\n", sum);
}

int isPrime(int num) {
    int i; // index
    int sq = sqrt(num);
    for(i = 2 ; i <= sq ; i++) {
        if(num % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This code leads to the correct answer, 142913828922.
But when I change the for loop in `isPrime()` to:

```
for(i = 2; i <= sq+1; i++)   // or even sq+2, sq+3, etc.
```

It leads to incorrect results such as 142913828920 and 142913828917, etc.

Why does it go wrong? Theoretically, it doesn't change the number `isPrime()` sends to `main()`, does it?

Comment: Maybe you use too big numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering you changed the sum from `142913828922` to `142913828920`, then the difference is `2`, which means you're interpreting `2` as not prime. Changing `sq` to `sq+1` should achieve that difference. Changing it to `sq+2` would end up making `3` not prime.

```
((int)sqrt(2))+1 == 2
((int)sqrt(3))+2 == 3
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  The logic trap now doesn't seem that tricky.

Answer (score 9):

if you change the loop to

```
for(i = 2 ; i <= sq+1 ; i++)
```

then 2 is no longer considered to be prime, because you test if `2 % 2 == 0`.

Similar for larger numbers you add, more and more primes will not be detected as such.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use

```
for(i = 2 ; i*i <= num ; i++) {
    if(num % i == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
int sq = sqrt(num);
for(i = 2 ; i <= sq ; i++) {
    if(num % i == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

to avoid this problems with sqrt function